# Box 2d Level Editor for AndEngine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I am getting started with Box2d in AndEngine.
I need to know if there is any level editor to be used with box2d and gives output capatable with AndEngine.

Is there any tool which can help me building complex body with joints like a bike or car?

What do you suggest which is the best way to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 6):

I think the [RUBE editor](https://www.iforce2d.net/rube/) might be what you're looking for. It does however export the box2d bodies in a JSON format, so you'll probably need to figure out yourself how to load these. It is very well documented tough.

Comment: You might like to check out this github that has a sample to load the JSON into AndEngine: https://github.com/LouisBHirst/AndEngineJb2dJson

Comment: Loading jason isnt an issue. Lets try lnkscape and GIMP.

Answer (score 2):

Here I provide a link for physics editor that I use regularly and very much easy for use. This editor creates xml file that you can use directly with andengine level parsing easily.

http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

Also for level creating purpose you can use Macromedia Flash, that editor directly return x and y position using scripting. So user have to directly parse that information.

Comment: I dont know how to make it in flash any help regarding that would be appreciated. And I am already using Physics Editor :)

Comment: For this you have to learn some what about flash.

Comment: Actually I find it kind of odd to suggest Flash, which to me seems very bloated(i.e. it has a lot more features not suitable for this purpose) for level creation. Unless of course you are making your whole game in Flash. A better vector-based alternative would be Inkscape. And if you want to make Raster-image objects, I'd suggest GIMP. Both programs are open-source and free.

Comment: Loading jason isnt an issue. Lets try inkscape and GIMP.
Oops these are image editing software how can they help me in level building.

Comment: In the end, a level is nothing more than a collection of shapes that the player can collide and interact with. Using any vector-based program you can create this collection of shapes. (And indeed also make them look nice.) See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUvqEh2tlCQ for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Level Director](http://www.retrofitproductions.com/level-director/) which was designed for the Corona SDK (which uses Box2d) but it now allows you to export the data using a template. The possibilities are now endless and I love it.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on my own level editor Fire Ant Box2d Level editor, is free, please feel free to try it out, it exports your work to ios code as well as xml so you only write a small xml processing routine and you should be able to use it in andengine. It also generates optimized texture tiles out of the box.

http://www.freefable.com

http://www.estebon.mx/fable

Any comment and feedback will be very apreciate.